# Why does "2;3;;" raise a warning that I should have provided a unit statement?

Tags: ocaml

I have found it difficult to grasp the use of the semicolon in OCaml. Initially, I believed it to be a separator for a sequence of expressions. However, I received a warning despite only attempting to concatenate two constant expressions. Why is there such a warning? Why should I provide a unit statement?

```
# 2; 3;;
Warning 10 [non-unit-statement]: this expression should have type unit.
- : int = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The `;` operator discards it left-hand side operand. Thus in

```ml
computation x; y
```

the result of the computation is discarded. In other words, if the computation is not doing any side effects,

```ml
computation x; y
```

is a less efficient and less readable way to write

```ml
y
```

Contrarily, if the point of calling `computation x` is that the computation is modifying some global state and nothing else, then the return type of `computation x` would be unit. And discarding unit is always fine since the value `()` does not contain one bit of information.

Note however that if `computation x` does modify a global state but returns a result status, ignoring the result status is probably a programming error.
If the expected use of `computation` is

```ml
match computation x with
| Ok () -> do_something ()
| Error msg -> Format.eprintf "@[Fatal error:@ %t@]@." msg; exit 2
```

writing

```ml
computation x; y
```

forgets to handle the error case.

Thus the `non-unit-statement` warning informs you when `;` is discarding information. The `-strict-sequence` flag goes one step further and makes this discarding an error:

```ml
1; 2
```

```
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         unit
       because it is in the left-hand side of a sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `;` is made to separate expressions. But since it doesn’t use the value of the first one, it will prefer a unit value : `()`.

You can type `ignore 2;3`. Or also `let _ = 2 in 3`. (Here, evaluating 2 and forgetting its value is not interesting, but other expressions have side-effect, and one of the two proposals can be handy).

`ignore` is a function from `Stdlib` which you could have declared with `let ignore _ = ()`

You can disable this warning with `ocaml -w -10` or `ocaml -w -non-unit-statement`.

Comment: More than a preference. Throwing away a non-unit value is a strong indication of a bug. It's therefore good practice to be explicit about it, and the warning encourages that practice,

Comment: Its is a preference since it raises a warning, not a type error. But yes, I prefer to `ignore` explicitly what I want to forget after verifying in each case it is not a bug, than to disable warnings.